# permission use in android.manifest in Android studio

Tags: android-studio

does anyone know what permission we have use in android.manifest in Android studio to make another app disable for some time like Google Well Being Application Which disables another app after using it for some time.

Comment: You can just restrict the use of your app being opened by another app. But your app/activity doesn't have any control over other apps or activities.

Comment: I am making an app to stop using the social app all days by disabling apps after using them for some time like google well being. so how can I disable another app using my app.

Comment: @AbhishekDutt callbacks pause(), stop() is used to pause and stop own app how can I use them to stop another app through my app any idea?

Comment: those callbacks are for the activities that you are currently working on, i.e. your app. You cannot use them to stop other activities, because of two things: 1. You don't know the address space of other activity(other app) 2. Other than the system Kernel, no other process can intercept another process.

Comment: What you can do is to just kill a background process using `ActivityManager.killBackgroundProcess()` , but I don't think so this is what you are looking for, isn't it?

Comment: @Abhishek Dutt I know about killing running activity in background but killing running activity doesn't stop user from opening that app again .

Comment: I want to make a restriction In which user can use it for some time like 2Hrs or 4Hrs that user can decide after the use time is over the user can't use app for rest of the day.